# How to import bootstrap 4 sass/scss from node_modules using gulp

Tags: gulp, node-modules, gulp-watch

I'm trying to @import some bootstrap 4 sass files from node_modules but my gulp watcher isn't picking up any changes to those node_modules bootstrap files.

In my main sass file  I'm importing bootstrap via:

```
@import "bootstrap-grid";
@import "bootstrap-reboot";
@import "custom";
```

Then I also import some "local" sass files (outside of node_modules):

```
@import "some-file";
@import "some-other-file";
etc.
```

These local sass files are watched fine, I get recompilation when I do my edits/file save.

My sass gulp task looks like this:

```
//compile sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/css/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/']
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'));
});
```

The key part for me to pick up the bootstrap files was to use the **includePaths** part.

I am getting the bootstrap grid and what I'm wanting to do is update the node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_custom.scss (which I'm importing) to place bootstrap overrides in.

I'm not quite sure how to get the bootstrap to recompile when I edit/save any node_modules bootstrap files.

I tried updating the includePaths to:

```
includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/**/*.scss']
```

But that throws an error, "file to import not found" (bootstrap-grid) which also seems odd to me because it seems like it should be adding/watching sass files (and any sub-directories) down in bootstrap/scss.

My file structure at this point is very simple:

```
root
  |
  | node_modules
      | bootstrap
         | scss
  | src
      | css
         | scss
gulpfile.js
```

Comment: Its a bad practice to customize the files present in node_modules. you can always load a custom css file after importing bootstrap files to override those values

Comment: OK, yeah, that's fair enough and I concur.  I'm just trying to figure out how to get recompilation from sass files that live in different directories.

Comment: you don't have to, if the import is already present in your scss file, sass compiler will take care of that.

Comment: That's the point of my question, when I make changes to bootstrap's _custom.scss down in node_modules, it isn't getting recompiled.  My "local" src/css/scss files are.  Looking back, my example is not the best because as you point out, you don't want to edit files in node_modules, but I'm just trying to figure out why I can't compile-on-save files outside src/css/scss

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the sass files from the node_modules to gulp.watch:

```
    gulp.watch([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/**/*.scss', 
        'src/css/scss/**/*.scss'
    ], ['sass']);
```

Hope that helps.